# Separation between two Gaussian distributions

Tags: particle-physics, statistics

I do not understand when two Gaussian distributions are considered separated, given the resolution of the variable.

Let us suppose we want to know if the difference between two times of flight is statistically relevant. Kleinknecht's book suggest a 4$\sigma_T$ separation, where $\sigma_T$ is the resolution of the apparatus. I have two questions:

- Why 4 $\sigma_T$? I assume it derives from summing 2$\sigma_T$ for each distribution, but in that case, since they are statistical errors, shouldn't it be $2\sqrt{2} \sigma_T$? Is the resolution considered a maximum error, even if we can plot the Gaussian distribution?
- Assuming that we measure N differences t1-t2. Does this allow us to consider 4 $\sigma_T/\sqrt{N}$, as the error on the mean? I suppose that not to be true, since the resolution is seen as a 'limit' to the separation between two variables. Maybe we refer to the variables t1 and t2, not their means? Then why we compute the difference as the difference between the two peaks?

Answer (score 1):

**First item:**
Statistical relevance is not an absolute  but a relative statement. The proper way of stating it is "this is stat. relevant on a $2\sigma$ level ($\approx 5\%$). Therefore, there is nothing wrong in using a $4 \sigma$ level. So it would help if you could state the exact sentence and context.

You second question I don't really understand.

> Is the resolution considered a maximum error, even if we can plot the Gaussian distribution?

In your example the resolution is the smallest time duration between two packages, which allows to detect them as separated packages. I reckon the [Rayleigh criterion](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/Raylei.html) could be used in your example. However, there are other definitions of resolution as well.

> Assuming that we measure $N$ differences $\Delta t = t_1-t_2$. Does this allow us to consider $4 \sigma_T / \sqrt{N}$, as the error on the mean?

**Second item:**
I guess you are mixing two concepts here.

- *statistical significant*: The difference $\Delta t$ is taken to be statistical significant on the $4\sigma_T$ level.
- *error of the mean*: If the error of a single datapoint is $\sigma_t$ then the error of the mean of $N$ datapoints is $\sigma_t/\sqrt{N}$. Be aware, that the resolution $\sigma_T$ doesn't have to be equal to the error $\sigma_t$: E.g. the resolution could be the resolution of the sensor (= a single component of the hole experiment), while the error could is the error made including *all* components of the experiment.

So, let's assume that $\sigma_t = \sigma_T$.  Then,

- if you take $N$ (independent and identical distributed) datapoints $(\Delta t_1, \Delta t_2, ... \Delta t_N)$,
- you can calc their mean value $\langle \Delta t\rangle = \frac{1}{n} \sum_j \Delta t_j$
- The standard deviation of the mean value is $\sigma_{\langle \Delta t\rangle} = \sigma_t/\sqrt{N}$
- Now you compare the mean value with its standard deviation. E.g. if the time differences are normally distributed you could calc the $z-value$ 
  $$z = \frac{\langle \Delta t\rangle - t_0}{\sigma_{\langle \Delta t\rangle}} = \frac{\langle \Delta t\rangle - t_0}{\sigma_t/\sqrt{N}}$$ 
  and calc the significance level for $\langle \Delta t\rangle$ be to a given value $t_0$, by using the standardized normal distribution $N(0,1)$. You are probably interested in $t_0 = 0s$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. About my second question, I was just asking why, if we want to check if the difference is statistically revelant to the 2$\sigma$ level, we use 4$\sigma$ for the difference. Shouldn't it be: $\sigma_ {\Delta t}$ = $\sqrt{2 * 4 \sigma_t ^2}$? As you suggested, I think I am mixing error propagation and distribution, so this might be the reason. I will check this thoroughly. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to check whether or not a signal, e.g. the difference $\Delta t$, is significant on a "$n\sigma$"-level, you should check $|\langle \Delta t\rangle - t_0| > n \sigma_{\Delta t}$.  However, I made a mistake above: As you do not know the standard deviation of the population, you have to use the  [Student's t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution), not the normal distribution as a reference.